# Spring Data JPA: Creating Specification Query Fetch Joins

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

**TL;DR**: How do you replicate JPQL Join-Fetch operations using specifications in Spring Data JPA?

I am trying to build a class that will handle dynamic query building for JPA entities using Spring Data JPA.  To do this, I am defining a number of methods that create `Predicate` objects (such as is suggested in the [Spring Data JPA docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#specifications) and elsewhere), and then chaining them when the appropriate query parameter is submitted.  Some of my entities have one-to-many relationships with other entities that help describe them, which are eagerly fetched when queried and coalesced into collections or maps for DTO creation. A simplified example:

```
@Entity
public class Gene {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="entrez_gene_id")
    privateLong id;

    @Column(name="gene_symbol")
    private String symbol;

    @Column(name="species")
    private String species;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="gene", fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
    private Set<GeneSymbolAlias> aliases;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="gene", fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
    private Set<GeneAttributes> attributes;

    // etc...

}

@Entity
public class GeneSymbolAlias {

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "alias_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="gene_symbol")
    private String symbol;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumn(name="entrez_gene_id")
    private Gene gene;

    // etc...

}
```

Query string parameters are passed from the `Controller` class to the `Service` class as key-value pairs, where they are processed and assembled into `Predicates`:

```
@Service
public class GeneService {

    @Autowired private GeneRepository repository;
    @Autowired private GeneSpecificationBuilder builder;

    public List<Gene> findGenes(Map<String,Object> params){
        return repository.findAll(builder.getSpecifications(params));
    }

    //etc...

}

@Component
public class GeneSpecificationBuilder {

    public Specifications<Gene> getSpecifications(Map<String,Object> params){
        Specifications<Gene> = null;
        for (Map.Entry param: params.entrySet()){
            Specification<Gene> specification = null;
            if (param.getKey().equals("symbol")){
                specification = symbolEquals((String) param.getValue());
            } else if (param.getKey().equals("species")){
                specification = speciesEquals((String) param.getValue());
            } //etc
            if (specification != null){
               if (specifications == null){
                   specifications = Specifications.where(specification);
               } else {
                   specifications.and(specification);
               }
            }
        } 
        return specifications;
    }

    private Specification<Gene> symbolEquals(String symbol){
        return new Specification<Gene>(){
            @Override public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Gene> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder){
                return builder.equal(root.get("symbol"), symbol);
            }
        };
    }

    // etc...

}
```

In this example, every time I want to retrieve a `Gene` record, I also want its associated `GeneAttribute` and `GeneSymbolAlias` records.  This all works as expected, and a request for a single `Gene` will fire off 3 queries: one each to the `Gene`, `GeneAttribute`, and `GeneSymbolAlias` tables.

The problem is that there is no reason that 3 queries need to run to get a single `Gene` entity with embedded attributes and aliases.  This can be done in plain SQL, and it can be done with a JPQL query in my Spring Data JPA repository:

```
@Query(value = "select g from Gene g left join fetch g.attributes join fetch g.aliases where g.symbol = ?1 order by g.entrezGeneId")
List<Gene> findBySymbol(String symbol);
```

How can I replicate this fetching strategy using Specifications?  I found [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482235/spring-data-jpa-fetching), but it only seems to make lazy fetches into eager fetches.

Comment: Did you try with `root.fetch()` inside `toPredicate()`? Something like `root.fetch("attributes", JoinType.LEFT)`

Comment: @PredragMaric: That will eagerly fetch the `attributes`, but it still requires an additional query.  I want all of the fetches to be part of a single query.

Comment: Yes, but another fetch for `aliases` should do it: `root.fetch("aliases", JoinType.LEFT)`

Comment: I have tried this before, as was suggested in the question I linked, but it does not achieve the desired result.  The problem is not that fetching the linked entities cannot be done with a single specification query, the problem is that the single specification query needs 3 SQL queries to get those entities, which is totally unnecessary.

Comment: I didn't get it all? What you want exactly that you need List of gene entity with the set of alises and attribute by writing specification?
In case you want List of Gene with specification so i can give you appropriate solution?

Comment: i have written a library to search on an entity with parameters, it creates hql queries using parameter objects. i use parameter classes instead of hashmap. https://github.com/ekremucar/hqlplus/ if you set a property of the parameter object it will be added to where clause. you can set search type (like, eq) and set fetch type of aliases.

Answer (score 38):

You can specify the join fetch while creating Specification but since the same specification will be used by pageable methods also
like findAll(Specification var1, Pageable var2) and count query will complain because of join fetch. Therefore, to handle that we can check the resultType of CriteriaQuery and apply join only if it is not Long (result type for count query). see below code:

```
    public static Specification<Item> findByCustomer(Customer customer) {
    return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        /*
            Join fetch should be applied only for query to fetch the "data", not for "count" query to do pagination.
            Handled this by checking the criteriaQuery.getResultType(), if it's long that means query is
            for count so not appending join fetch else append it.
         */
        if (Long.class != criteriaQuery.getResultType()) {
            root.fetch(Person_.itemInfo.getName(), JoinType.LEFT);
        }
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Person_.customer), customer);
    };
}
```

Comment: This answer saved by soul.

Comment: What about: root.getJavaType() == criteriaQuery.getResultType()

Comment: You are the Man!!, You are the Woman in case you're a lady!

Answer (score 36):

Specification class:

```
public class MatchAllWithSymbol extends Specification<Gene> {
    private String symbol;

    public CustomSpec (String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Gene> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

        //This part allow to use this specification in pageable queries
        //but you must be aware that the results will be paged in   
        //application memory!
        Class clazz = query.getResultType();
        if (clazz.equals(Long.class) || clazz.equals(long.class))
            return null;

        //building the desired query
        root.fetch("aliases", JoinType.LEFT);
        root.fetch("attributes", JoinType.LEFT);
        query.distinct(true);        
        query.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("entrezGeneId")));
        return cb.equal(root.get("symbol"), symbol);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    List<Gene> list = GeneRepository.findAll(new MatchAllWithSymbol("Symbol"));
```

Comment: Nice tip on how to make a specification work with SDJPA pageable queries. +1.

Comment: it works but the problem hibernate does pagination in memory and in console i see this message 'HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!' , I Try to resolve it with fetch join and entity graph but I don't find a perfect solution .

Comment: could it be that hibernate does the in-memory stuff because when it uses the specification as a count query, the predicate is null? the other answer to this question does not return null, but instead just refrains from applying the joins when it is called as a count query. looks safer to me, but i am not completely sure whether this would fix the in-memory paging issue. i am no hibernate expert, this is just an educated guess on my part ^^