# OneToMany lazy initialization when needing collection data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

What's a workaround if I have a relation `OneToMany` and would like to access the collection that is lazy loaded? Currently I get `LazyInitializationException` having this:

`Club` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Club {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "club", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Player> players;
```

`Player` entity:

Is it a good idea to have two methods, where one fetches data without players and the second one that fetches also players?

```
    @Override
    List<Club> findAll();

    @Query("Select clubs from Club clubs left join fetch clubs.players")
    List<Club> getAllClubsWithPlayers();
```

What I'm thinking of is that it is a bad idea, because if I have a situation where I have for example 4 properties that are lazy loaded and I'd need at once 3 of them, I'd have to have a query like: `getAllClubsWithPlayersAndSponsorsAndCoaches`, so I'd have to have a lot of combinations of such queries.
I don't want to use `EAGER`, so could you tell me if it's a common way to do this if I need access to `players` from the `Club` sometimes which is undoable with the `findAll()` method that throws `LazyInitializationException`?

Don't get me wrong - I know where the `LazyInitializationException` comes from, but I just don't know what's the best way to get access to `players` if I sometimes need them when fetching `clubs`. Is my way of doing it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 choices:

1. Access all the lazy fields inside a `@Transactional` method. You don't show your code, but there's usually a Service Facade layer which is responsible for being `@Transactional`. It invokes Repositories.
2. Write a query that fetches all the required data. Then you'd have to create a method specifically to fetch all the lazy fields required for that logic.
3. Use OpenSessionInViewFilter or OpenSessionInViewInterceptor so that Session/EntityManager are started before the execution even reaches the Controller. The Session then would be closed by the same high-level layer at the end of the request processing.

Comment: I'm just an idiot - I was debugging my code inside the controller call, not the actual service that was calling the repository - that's why it was throwing the initialization here. Thanks for that "refreshing the brain".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Stanislav wrote, I'd like to elaborate on his 2nd point, because I think that this is often the best approach - that's simply because it saves unnecessary calls to the database which results in better performance.

Apart from writing separate JPQL query in your repository for each use-case, you could do one of the following .:

1. Make your repository extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor` and programmatically describe what needs to be fetched as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40793243/6700091)
2. Use Entity Graph either described using annotations, or programmatically, and fetch your entities using `EntityManager` as described in [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph)

Answer (score 0):

To optionally load what you want you can use EntityGraph.

Declare `@NamedEntityGraph` at your entity

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Club.players",
    attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("players")
)
public class Club {
```

Then you should annotate your `findAll()` method with this graph using it's name

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Club.players")
List<Club> findAll();
```

However that would override your basic `findAll()` method.
To avoid this (to have both implementations) you can follow this way:

Add dependency from `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cosium.spring.data/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph/<version>`

Then replace your repository with

```
@Repository
public interface ClubRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<Club>, JpaRepository<Club, Long>, EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor<Club> {

}
```

And then you'll have basic method `findAll()` and also from your sevice you can call

```
List<Club> clubs = clubRepository.findAll(specification, new NamedEntityGraph(EntityGraphType.FETCH, "Club.players"))
```